# upgrade project angular 8 to 10 getting error '0' of undefined ng serve

Tags: angular

I upgraded my angular application from version 8 to version 10. Now after running ng serve I am getting below one-liner error ERROR in Cannot read property '0' of undefined

tried clearing npm cache, deleted the package.json file, deleted node_modules, and install the npm packages again but nothing seems to help me.

**this is my package.json file**

```
 {
  "name": "equality-mh",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "tsc": "tsc -p src -w",
    "start": "live-server --open=src",
    "build-prod": "node --max_old_space_size=5048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod",
    "build-prod-aot": "node --max_old_space_size=5048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --aot --build-optimizer --configuration=production"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^10.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~11.0.0-next.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~10.1.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^9.0.0-beta.31",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^10.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~10.1.0",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^3.7.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "@nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to": "^3.0.1",
    "adyen-api-js": "^1.30.4",
    "angular-6-social-login": "^1.1.1",
    "angular-google-charts": "^0.1.6",
    "angular-morris-js": "^1.1.0",
    "angular-tinymce": "^6.0.0",
    "angular2-image-zoom": "^1.2.1",
    "angular2-masonry": "^0.4.0",
    "angular2-notifications": "^2.0.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-rc.5",
    "http": "0.0.0",
    "imagesloaded": "^4.1.4",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jw-angular-social-buttons": "^1.0.0",
    "ng-lazyload-image": "^7.0.1",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.3.0",
    "ng6-file-upload": "^1.1.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.1.1",
    "ngx-editor": "^4.1.0",
    "ngx-emoji-picker": "0.0.2",
    "ngx-facebook": "^2.4.0",
    "ngx-image-cropper": "^2.0.2",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^8.0.1",
    "ngx-mat-select-search": "^2.1.1",
    "ngx-skeleton-loader": "^1.2.6",
    "ngx-slick": "^0.2.1",
    "primeicons": "^2.0.0",
    "primeng": "^8.0.2",
    "quill": "^1.3.6",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.2",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.3.0",
    "stripe-angular": "^1.0.2",
    "swiper": "^5.2.0",
    "tinymce": "^5.0.14",
    "ts-md5": "^1.2.4",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1001.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/language-service": "~10.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know, but it's possible you has erros in yours FormArrays. The last recurse is create a new angular project in Angular 10, add the librarys you have in the old projects and replace the src by the old one

Comment: I have already done this but the same error is coming in the other project

Comment: Is your angular cli upgraded globally?

Comment: @Piyush yes cli updated globally

Comment: Ok, can you please add screenshot of error or paste full trace here?

Comment: Did you resolve this?